# How to use left outer join in my sql query?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Here is my query:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_logdetails
(
    @bookid INT
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM book_lending
    LEFT OUTER JOIN student ON student.id = book_lending.id
    WHERE bookid = @bookid
END
```

When i execute above query, it shows only book_lending data, not the student data. Here is my [**screenshot**](http://s21.postimg.org/c0kyu3c13/untitled1.jpg)

And it is my student table data [**screenshot**](http://s21.postimg.org/58ujr8n1j/untitled.jpg):

May i know, how to get student data in which particular bookid. I used to set foreign key for book_lending id to student id.

Can anyone guide me to fix this?

Thanks,

Comment: Replace your WHERE with AND

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the fields mixed up in the join:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN student ON student.id = book_lending.id
```

You try to match a student to book lending by ID of both - which is wrong.

Change the code to this and you will start getting results back:

```
SELECT *
FROM book_lending
LEFT OUTER JOIN student ON student.id = book_lending.studentid
WHERE bookid = @bookid
```

Comment: Now i got data on new window.. what can i do to show in pop up..? thanks

Comment: here is my existing code:  Response.Write("<script>");
            Response.Write("window.open('loginfo.aspx?id=" + btn.CommandArgument + "','_blank')"); 
            Response.Write("</script>");

Comment: No idea @Rani, please try yourself some more and if you get to a dead end post new question.

Answer (score 2):

Select the specific columns from joined table in your select list. Here `bl` and `s` is table alias for better redability. You need to select the columns you want and include them to your select list. below query will select all columns from both tables.

```
SELECT bl.*, s.*
FROM book_lending bl
LEFT OUTER JOIN student s ON s.id = bl.id
AND bl.bookid = @bookid
```

Comment: Sorry i can;t able to understand, can you please elaborate with my query

Comment: See edit in answer if that helps. consider learning about SQL.

Comment: again i got same issue.. student data becomes null only

Comment: This shouldn't really matter, tested it now just to be sure and select * return all columns. Maybe not best practice, but don't think that's the issue here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, I have no idea what all columns OP looking for and so `*` to just so an example.

Comment: @Rani, you will get null for students record wherever there is no match.

Comment: How can i get student data?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - OP never said they received any error, OP's question was _it shows only book_lending data, not the student data and how to get student data._

Comment: @Rani that wasn't my point. My point is, you did not address the real problem.

Comment: @Rani, post your table structure for book_lending table.